# Linq to Entities query non primitive type

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this method I wrote as:

```
private void GetReceivedInvoiceTasks(User user, List<Task> tasks)
        {
            var taskList = from i in _db.Invoices
                           join a in user.Areas on i.AreaId equals a.AreaId
                           where i.Status == InvoiceStatuses.Received
                           select i;

        }
```

Basically I was trying to get all the Invoices in the database in the user's area that have a status of received. I don't understand LINQ too well right now.

I'm getting the error:

> base {System.SystemException} = {"Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'Models.Area'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and
>   Guid') are supported in this context."}

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to remedy this? I can't currently understand what the problem is. If I take the `join` line out it's fine but I really need that line to make sure I only have invoices from the users area/areas (they can belong to more than one area). Have I got something fundamentally wrong with this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework does not support joins with in-memory collections. You will have to re-wire your query to make use of a `Contains` query with a collection of primitives instead.

Also EF currently does not support enum values so you will have to compare with an integer value (If `InvoiceStatuses.Received` is not an `enum` value ignore this part).

Both fixes combined lead to the following query approach which should result in results equivalent to your join:

```
int statusReceived = (int)InvoiceStatuses.Received;
var areaIds = user.Areas.Select(x=> x.AreaId).ToArray();

var taskList = from i in _db.Invoices
               where i.Status == statusReceived && areaIds.Contains(i.AreaId)
               select i;
```