# LINQ to Entities - method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

The same query worked in .Net 3.5 but not in .Net 4.5.2 
There are lots of posts here with the same error, and tried almost all but of no use.
I have extracted everything into a separate variable for querying. Still i am getting the error -

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
 private void LoadAppointmentData()
        {
            var user = Session["user"].ToString();
            var userFirstName = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.FirstName == user);

            var userFN = userFirstName.username;
            var chwWorker = from c in db.PatientContacts
                            where c.UserName == userFN &&
                                 (c.PCP_Status == "Appointment Made" || c.PCP_Status_AWC == "Appointment Made"
                                   || c.PCP_Status_AWDV == "Appointment Made" ||
                                 (c.PCP_Status == "RX for Mamogram" && c.Status == "Appointment Made")) 
                            orderby c.PCP_Status_Date descending 
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = c.MemberID,
                                Name = c.PatientFirstName + " " + c.PatientLastName, 
                                PCP_Appt = $"{c.PCP_Status_Date:d}",
                                Mammogram_Appt = $"{c.StatusDate:d}",
                                Phone = GetPhone(c.MemberID)
                            };
            if (chwWorker.Any())
            {
                if (grvAppointmentList != null)
                {
                    pnlAppointmentFollowUp.Visible = true;
                    grvAppointmentList.DataSource = chwWorker;
                    grvAppointmentList.DataBind();
                }
            }
}
```

I am not sure what else to change to make this query run.

Comment: `$"{c.PCP_Status_Date:d}"` [is `String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). I assume you know what the error means.

Comment: but the same worked in the earlier version...

Comment: Nope, string.Format has never been a supported method in Entity Framework. I assume you used LINQ-to-SQL in .Net 3.5, which auto-switched to client-side evaluation for parts in the LINQ query that couldn't be translated into SQL.

Comment: I tried converting to PCP_Appt = string.Format("{0:d}", c.PCP_Status_Date), and still getting the same error - "  Message "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." s

Comment: @GertArnold, Yes you are right, I used LINQ-to-SQL in .Net 3.5,

Comment: There are tons of posts explaining the meaning of "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method...". As usual: let EF get the data, do formatting later in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "LINQ to Objects" to perform `string.Format` or interpolated strings by using `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` before using `Select`:

```
var chwWorker = (from c in db.PatientContacts
                where c.UserName == userFN &&
                     (c.PCP_Status == "Appointment Made" || c.PCP_Status_AWC == "Appointment Made"
                      || c.PCP_Status_AWDV == "Appointment Made" ||
                     (c.PCP_Status == "RX for Mamogram" && c.Status == "Appointment Made")) 
                orderby c.PCP_Status_Date descending select c) 
                .AsEnumerable() // or 'ToList()'
                .Select(c => new 
                {
                     Id = c.MemberID,
                     Name = c.PatientFirstName + " " + c.PatientLastName, 
                     PCP_Appt = $"{c.PCP_Status_Date:d}",
                     Mammogram_Appt = $"{c.StatusDate:d}",
                     Phone = GetPhone(c.MemberID)
                });
```

Note that `string.Format` method is not recognized by LINQ to Entities to translate it as an SQL command, hence query result materialization to memory is necessary.

NB: You can use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) if you still want LINQ to Entities query before using `Any()` method, but not all SQL providers able to translate it into SQL statement.

Related issue:

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215971/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-format)

Comment: Thanks @Tetsuya Yamamoto - I had to use the Select operator for the query to work like this "... orderby c.PCP_Status_Date descending select c) .AsEnumerable()..." and it works fine now.  Other wise, it's throwing a "A query body must end with select clause or group clause.  Thanks for your help in resolving this.