# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String IfNullOrWhiteSpace'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So, I have this search query giving me an error now. (It didn't used too, fyi...)
anyway, it's throwing "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String IfNullOrWhiteSpace"...

Is there a beter way of doing this?

```
 var stringResults = _propertyRepository
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(
                // standard fields
                x => x.Address.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString)
                     || x.City.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString)
                     || x.WebsiteUrl.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString)
                     || x.Zip.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString)
                    // overrides possible
                     || (x.DescriptionOverride ? x.DescriptionOverrideValue.Contains(searchString) : x.Description.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString))
                     || (x.NameOverride ? x.NameOverrideValue.Contains(searchString) : x.Name.Contains(searchString))
                     || (x.SquareFootageOverride ? x.SquareFootageOverrideValue.ToString().Contains(searchString) : x.SquareFootage.ToString().Contains(searchString))
                    // tags
                     || (x.TagsOverride ? x.TagsOverrideValue.Any(f => f.TagName.Contains(searchString)) : x.Tags.Any(f => f.TagName.Contains(searchString)))
                    // bayoptions
                     || x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.BaySizeOverride ? g.BaySizeOverrideValue.ToString().Contains(searchString) : g.BaySize.ToString().Contains(searchString))
                     || x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.DescriptionOverride ? g.DescriptionOverrideValue.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString) : g.Description.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString))
                     || x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.ExcerptOverride ? g.ExcerptOverrideValue.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").Contains(searchString) : g.Excerpt.IfNullOrWhiteSpace("").ToString().Contains(searchString))
                    // Freeform Fields
                     || x.FreeFormFields.Any(g => g.NumberValue.ToString().Contains(searchString))
                     || x.FreeFormFields.Any(g => g.StringValue != null && g.StringValue.ToString().Contains(searchString))
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Where did you define that method? It's not in the BCL. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` *is* however.

Comment: IsNullOrWhiteSpace, not IfNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: what about: .Where(x => !(x.Address == null || x.Address.Trim() == String.Empty))

Comment: @ojf no, it is 'IfNullOrWhiteSpace'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IfNullOrWhiteSpace` is a custom extension method, so the L2E provider does not know what to do with it.

You don't need to do any null checks when doing a `Contains` in L2E, so you can just remove the `IfNullOrWhiteSpace` part.

Comment: I was using it to catch nulls, otherwise it was breaking at this line. I've since modified my code with an additional && x.City != null to account for it and removed IfNullOrWhiteSpace. thanks again.

Comment: FYI, I  didn't write any custom extension, this was available to me without customizations.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have defined IfNullOrWhiteSpace then the function should be IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

Gee thanks for the downvotes...possible dupe of this question if the method is spelt correctly?
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-formatsystem-stri)

(cue more downvotes no doubt)

Comment: If the method didn't exist, the code wouldn't compile at all and OP wouldn't be getting the error he has.

Comment: Even that (`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`) shouldn't work with LINQ to entities.

Comment: @stijn That's a build error, not a runtime error isnt it?

Comment: It's a runtime error. Different providers support a different feature set, so it could not possibly be a compile time error.

Comment: fyi, i did NOT define IfNullOrWhiteSpace, it was available.

Comment: are you sure? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=IfNullOrWhiteSpace&oq=IfNullOrWhiteSpace&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8