# Why throws exception when using Guid.Parse() method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a WebApi application where I have written a method to get the Student using the following code:

```
    public Student GetStudent(string studentId)
    {
        var student = this.context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Guid.Parse(studentId));
        return student;
    }
```

Here the studentId is getting from a WebApi call. But when I tried to run this application it throws an exception like:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there any one tell me why this is occurred and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all when you use `EntityFramework`, it will try to convert the `Guid.Parse()` method to a SQL and it fails to do that as it cannot convert to SQL statement/ 'store expression'.

You should just move the string parsing out of store expression and parse the string to `Guid` value before using it in the Query.

```
    public Student GetStudent(string studentId)
    {
        var stdId = Guid.Parse(studentId);
        var student = this.context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == stdId);
        return student;
    }
```

Comment: So, I cannot use any type of method calling in a LINQ query?

Comment: you can use methods EF can translate to SQL. That's just how EF/L2SQL works, translating LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Mainul Good observation. I wish EF would just refactor it internally rather than having to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this approach:

```
public Student GetStudent(string studentId)
{
    var student = (from c in this.context.Students
                  let guidId = Guid.Parse(studentId)
                  where c.Id == guidId
                  select c).FirstOrDefault();

    return student;
}
```

In this approach `let` allows You to create new temporary variable, that might be used later in `LinqToEntities` query.

I agree with @Mainul answer regarding reason of exception:

> Firt of all when you use EntityFramework, this will tried to convert
>   the Guid.Parse() method to a SQL and it fails to do that as it cannot
>   convert to SQL statement/ 'store expression'.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080047/1982631)

> Entity Framework is trying to execute your projection on the SQL side,
>   where there is no equivalent to string.Format. Use AsEnumerable() to
>   force evaluation of that part with Linq to Objects

Your case tries to evaluate `Guid.Parse` transformed to SQL query which is not found in SQL.

This happened with me also when I was trying to operate date part as-

```
var query = db.Table.Where(f=> f.Date == paramDate.Date.AddDays(-1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, I may add, instead of `string studentId` for signature, use `Guid studentId` since that's what you need anyway.  And this makes it clear that studentId is a `guid`, not a `string` to the caller.  If the caller wants to use the the returning `Student` object, you don't want him to do this `string studentid = student.Id`.  You want him to do this `Guid myStudentId = student.Id`.