# Return unique values only in Webapi controller

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following line in a WebApi controller;

```
string Codes = i.Products.FirstOrDefault().Code
```

As the line states, it gets the code, from the first Product.

But, what I really want it to do is to get all unique codes, and return them as a comma separated string.

So, let's say, there are 6 related products, and they have the following codes:

- 45
- 54
- 45
- 120
- 54
- 45

Right now, the statement just returns "45", given the above data.

But I want the statement above to return "45, 54, 120" (as a string).

How do I do this?

Complete code:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebAPI.Models.Product> Products { get; set; }
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

var product = await db.Products.Select(i =>
                new ProductDTO()
                {
                    Id = i.Id,
                    Created = i.Created,
                    Title = i.Title,                    
                    Codes = i.Products.FirstOrDefault().Code

                }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: Do you need your controller to return a collection of codes or a string concatenation of these codes?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Distinct`and `String.Join` works for you.Please try this:

```
var product = await db.Products.AsEnumerable()//Turn AsEnumarable
.Select(i =>
   new ProductDTO()
   {
     Id = i.Id,
     Created = i.Created,
     Title = i.Title,                    
     Codes = string.Join(",", 
               i.Products.Select(l => l.Code).Distinct())
   }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: DistinctBy? Do you mean Distinct?

Comment: It is extension method for linq. If you want you can look [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/wikis/OperatorsOverview.wiki)

Comment: thx @AlperTungaArslan But i get an error 'cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable<string> to string (Codes is a string)?

Comment: I am unsure how i can merge this into my excisting code. I updated my question with some more of my code?

Comment: I now get 'IEnumerable<ProductDTO> does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefaultAsync'.. :/

Comment: Make sure you have added System.Data.Entity namespace to your usings. This is an extension method, and it will not be available until you add appropriate namespace. @brother

Answer (score 0):

To convert to a comma separated list:

```
IEnumerable<string> distinctCodes = i.Products.Select(product => product.Code).Distinct();

return string.Join(",", distinctCodes);
```

But it's probably better if your controller returns a collection of string instead of a concatenated string.

Edit, after OP code update:

```
var DBProduct = await db.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

IEnumerable<string> productCodes = DBProduct.Products.Select(p => p.Code).Distinct();

var product = new ProductDTO()
{
   Id = DBProduct.Id,
   Created = DBProduct.Created,
   Title = DBProduct.Title,                    
   Codes = string.Join(",", productCodes)
};
```

Comment: I updated my question, with more of the code. I am unsure how i would incorporate your answer, with my code above?

Comment: I get this error 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: You must turn AsEnumerable before string.join look this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-formatsystem-stri)

Comment: I now get 'IEnumerable<ProductDTO> does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefaultAsync'.. :/