# The LINQ expression could not be translated in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm having trouble getting a specific value into the `Untis_Prof`field.

Code Sample:

```
foreach (EnseignantReport test in grades)
{
    test.Untis_Prof = this._dbContext.Teachers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => 
        test.Untis_Prof == string.Join(" ", new[] {c.LastName, c.FirstName }))
        .Result.UntisCode;
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression `'DbSet<Teacher>()`
>     `.Where(t => __progress_EnteringTeacherName_0 == string.Format(`
>         `format: "{0} {1}",`
>         `arg0: t.LastName,`
>         `arg1: t.FirstName))'` 
> could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method `'string.Format'` failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at 
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
> at 
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error message you've shown doesn't match the code sample (there is no `string.Format` in the code sample)

Comment: Have you tried just creating the string without calling another method to do so? Perhaps if you did something like: `$"{c.LastName} {c.FirstName}"` (or `c.LastName + " " + c.FirstName`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-formatsystem-stri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this not work for you?

```
foreach (EnseignantReport test in grades)
{
    test.Untis_Prof = this._dbContext.Teachers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => 
        test.Untis_Prof == c.LastName + " " + c.FirstName }))
        .Result.UntisCode;
}
```

Linq to DB, does not understand how to turn string.Join to a database query. You will either have to work around this, or get all the teachers in memory  `this._dbContext.Teachers.AsEnumerable` and then query on the enumerable by using c# code.

By the way, using `.Result` is not a good practice, it's better to use the non async `FirstOrDefault` function if you can't use `await`. You are in danger of getting a deadlock.